# Fetch Ajax POST URL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am wanting to retrieve the URL of a POST coming in via AJAX. I have created a router that manages all the requests from the user e.g GET and POST. I am just having trouble with retrieving the URL which AJAX is posting from. I can detect that the request is a post but don’t know how to find the URL.

I’ve already tried using `$_SERVER[“HTTP_REFERER”]`. This returns the current URL, not the AJAX POST unfortunately.

For example,

```
$.ajax({
          url: '/blah',
          data: form_data,
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: function (data) {
            var a = $.parseJSON(data);
              alert(a.message);
          },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
          }
        });
```

The url for this is '/blah' because all requests are running through my router, it's going to send the post request into my router which will then handle the information in which it returns. I just cannot seem to fetch this url inside of my router though.

Comment: Please add your code also in question.

Comment: done thanks @VaibhaviSojitra

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER[“REQUEST_URI”]` or `$_SERVER[“REDIRECT_URL”]` to get the same.

Comment: Yes, $_SERVER[“REQUEST_URI”] will give the url which is being called using Ajax.